# Reflecting unreviewed edit in answer editing page

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits

If  I edit a question that is not mine, then my edit is visible only to me until it is pair reviewed, but when I am editing my answer on this question I see original question's text not the edited text.

here is the original question
<kbd>[image: Question Before Edit]</kbd>

now I have edited the question, Edited text is only visible to me
<kbd>[image: Edited Question]</kbd>

here I have answered the question, still the edited text is visible to me
<kbd>[image: Question Answered]</kbd>

now if I want to edit my answer, I see the original question not the edited one
<kbd>[image: Editing Answer, your edit to question is not visible here]</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, now it's clear. Think there is a dupe, will search later. (no time now, just voted to Reopen)